# Is there a way to use JQM button styling outside of a Page or Header data-role?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I just started working with JQM a little while ago. I used the default VS2012 asp.net mobile project to start with. I like how the mobile pages work, but wanted a fixed area at the top of each page that essentially has 3 columns one of which is a logo. I've done that (with a basic table to start with) in the _layout.cshtml, and right below that is where I start the JQM Page layout. This is all working well, and I like how the page transitions happen while keeping a fixed header area at the top.

However, I would like to add a button to my fixed area at the top that is styled similar to the other JQM buttons. This doesn't work because the buttons are not within a valid Page or Header data-role I presume. Is there a way to take advantage of the JQM styles for HTML that is outside of those data-roles?

As an example, I'd like to use the anchor tag for a Log In button and have it styled the same as it is with a gear-icon when it's within a div that has data-role = "header". I'm not sure I have a deep enough understanding to drill down through all the elements that are used in the .css file and was hoping there are other individual classes or something I can take advantage of.

This is the line I am trying to display as a button, but I am only getting text (does work as anchor tag though):

```
<a data-role="button" data-transition="pop" href="/Vision/Account/Login">Log in</a>
```

Also, I am using jquery.mobile-1.1.0 and jquery-1.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style any element as a button by calling the jQuery Button Widget on the element:

```
$('.login-button').button();
```

The button function also accepts options such as the icon and theme:

```
$('.login-button').button({
    icon: 'gear'
});
```

See also: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect and opens up some options for me. I appreciate the help.

Comment: It appears that in order to change things like the icon and theme I needed to do the following instead: $('.login-button').buttonMarkup({ icon: "gear", theme: "b" }); Thanks for heading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding data-role="button" to your anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks, but I just edited to include what I have so far. It does go to the page and uses the transition though, but it only displays as text.

Comment: Oh what version of JQM are you using?

Comment: Using jquery.mobile-1.1.0 and jquery-1.7.2.